# Jquery Progressbar animate

Tags: jquery, animate, progress-bar, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста как можно анимировать Progressbar до текущего значения и после завершения анимации отобразить 2 блока?
http://jsfiddle.net/xmocartx/5N3Bf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Создаем progressbar, значение value ставим минимальным
    var bar = $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 0.1, max: 50000 });

    $('.ui-progressbar-value', bar).animate({

        // Выставляем ширину ползунка вручную
        width: 34513 / 50000 * 100 + '%'

    }, 2000, function() {

        // Обновляем значение
        $('#progressbar').progressbar("value", 34513);

        // Для проверки корректно выставленного значения
        $('#value').text(bar.progressbar( "value" ));

        // Отображаем блоки, можно использовать просто show()
        $('#value, #max').fadeIn();

    });

});
```

Блоки появляющиеся позже первоначально необходимо скрыть при помощи CSS.

**ДЕМО**: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/5N3Bf/4/

Comment: Класс! Последний вопросик, как вывести max значение в div? Так, как Вы value вывели не выходит..

Comment: Сразу после создания `progressbar` добавьте: `$('#value').text(50000);`

Comment: Ага,а я думал можно как то вывод самой макс переменной бара вывысти? В принципе это не критично, спасибо Вам огромное за помощь!

Comment: Если значеие нужно получить после создания, то можно так: `$('#max').text(bar.attr('aria-valuemax'));`

Comment: Красота!))